# JavaScript refactor not working - getElementById returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a script that displays an error message if there aren't enough words in a textarea.

It works just fine when I explicitly state the element I'm targeting:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="trainee[about]">About <span>(Minimum 20 words)</span></label>
  <textarea id="aboutText" type="text" name="trainee[about]" cols="80" rows="10" onkeypress="activateSubmit();">
    <%= @profile["about"] %>
  </textarea>
  <p id="aboutError" class="word-error">Min. 20 words!</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function activateSubmit(){
  var len = $('#aboutText').val().split(" ").length;
  console.log(len);
  if(len >= 20) { 
    document.getElementById('aboutError').style.display = "none";
  } else {
      document.getElementById('aboutError').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

And yet when I try and refactor it so I can use it on multiple for fields I get an error saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Here's the refactored code:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="trainee[about]">About <span>(Minimum 20 words)</span></label>
  <textarea id="aboutText" type="text" name="trainee[about]" cols="80" rows="10" onkeypress="activateSubmit(aboutText, aboutError);">
            <%= @profile["about"] %>
  </textarea>
  <p id="aboutError" class="word-error">Min. 20 words!</p>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
function activateSubmit(idText,idError){
  var len = $(idText).val().split(" ").length;
  console.log(len);
  if(len >= 20) { 
    document.getElementById(idError).style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(idError).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

The Javascript is at the bottom of the page so it shouldn't be the case that the element hasn't loaded yet, plus it worked before the refactor.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You need quotes here `onkeypress="activateSubmit(aboutText, aboutError);` **==>** `onkeypress="activateSubmit('aboutText', 'aboutError');`. Also, why not using jQuery.

Comment: I'll also suggest to use jQuery's `on` to bind events. `$('#aboutText').on('keyup', function() { $('#aboutError').toggle($(this).val().split(/\s+/).length < 20); });`

Comment: Ah so obvious! Thanks very much, appreciate it. The reason I'm not using jQuery is because I really don't know any, very new to JS and just trying to get something temporary going whilst I learn more

Comment: just add style="display:block;" to textarea by default on page load.Because you are using Javascript to show hide your error message and style attribute is not in texarea.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the `arguments` properly in the inline event handler,

```
 .... onkeypress="activateSubmit('aboutText', 'aboutError');">
```

But the best way could be avoid using inline handlers, see the below code,

```
$("#aboutText").keypress(function(){
  $(this).next("#aboutError").toggle($(this).val().split(" ").length <= 19)
});
```

Or a decent approach would be creating a class and adding it at the time,

**CSS:**

```
.hide{ display:none; }
p.show{ display:block; }
```

**JS:**

```
var erroElem = $("#aboutText").keypress(function(){
  erroElem.toggleClass("show", ($(this).val().split(" ").length < 20))
}).next("#aboutError").addClass("hide");
```

Comment: @Tushar And we can also write it like `<=19` :D

Comment: @Tushar Was kidding actually! Just used `<20` in newer version

Comment: Here are few suggstions: **1.** `$(this).next("#aboutError")` why? Just use `$("#aboutError")` because IDs are **unique**.  **2.** Use `split(/\s+/)`

Comment: @Tushar I just made use of chaining. Also I personally feel regex delimiters are hard to read at times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function activateSubmit(idText,idError){
var len = $('#'+idText).val().split(" ").length;
  console.log(len);
if(len >= 20) { 
  document.getElementById(idError).style.display = "none";
} else {
  document.getElementById(idError).style.display = "block";
}
```

}